# How to implement a paragraph system in cq-day

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I need a short description how to implement a paragraph system in day's Communique (cq).

I searched in the documentation of cq and in google, but did not find a simple explanation, which works.

Can anyone give me a small explanation?

It would be very helpful and appreciated. Thanks in advance.

(I need the description for CQ4.2)

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what does "paragraph system" means?

Comment: You question seems to ask how to implement default CMS functionality? (Though as David says below, my experience is also in 5.x) Could you give more details on what in particular is causing you a problem? Even if it wasn't default functionality, the scope of your question is too wide.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, 4.2 is a relatively old version of the Communiqué CMS.  The current version is CQ 5.5.  I am most familiar with 5.4, so some of my information may not be applicable to your case.

And as you may know, a paragraph system is a foundation component, functionality provided by the CMS.  You can include a "parsys" as a component in a page template; and you can extend the component, adding your own functionality.  So, in this context, I'm not sure what you mean by "implementing a paragraph system."

The docs for 4.2 are still available at http://docs.day.com/en/home/communique_4.html.  You might also want to check the knowledge base at http://dev.day.com/content/kb/home/cq5.html and the forum at http://forums.adobe.com/community/digital_marketing_suite/cq5.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I mean inserting a paragraph system as component to a template.
This means inserting parsys to the content management system.

Answer (score 0):

What I need to do was to initialize in front of including the parsys component.

The code I have to add in front of component parsys was:

```
<%
Style actstyle = null; 
%>
<cfc:initComponent cellId="body" componentId="/libs/Components/body">
<% actstyle = componentContext.getStyle(); %>
</cfc:initComponent>
<cfc:includeComponent cellId="body" componentId="/libs/Components/body" />


<cfc:includeComponent cellId="parsys"
    componentId="/apps/emb/Components/parsys" />
```

Additionally inside the components I need an editbar.
This is also nowhere described.

```
<%
ComponentContext cc = (ComponentContext) request.getAttribute("componentContext");
ComponentInfo ci = cc.getComponentInfo();
%>

<cfc:editbar
    parName="<%= cc.getContainerList() %>"
    parNum="<%= cc.getContainerLabel() %>"
    storagePre="<%= cc.getStoragePre() %>"
    dialogAny="<%= ci.getContentDialog() %>"
/>
```

Regards, Seboeh